# DynamicReports vs. DynamicJasper

Tags: jasper-reports

### Background

Developing Java EE application with [DynamicReports](http://dynamicreports.sourceforge.net/) and so far it's sufficient for me. Recently I found [DynamicJasper](http://dynamicjasper.com/) and I would like to know if it could be better choice.

I can see that DynamicReports may have better [support](http://sourceforge.net/apps/phpbb/dynamicreports/) and community.

### Questions

- What have been your experiences with both libraries?
- Which offers better functionality?
- What are strengths and weakness of each other?

Thank you!

Comment: wat's the prob with opinions if they are well reasoned. Eventually its upto the readers to accept the opinion or reject it. upvoted the Qs

Comment: In these answers I find a lot of facts, references and specific expertise.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

This question touches a few ways to create reports using the JasperReports API (either directly or indirectly):

- iReport
- JasperReports API
- [DynamicJasper](http://dynamicjasper.com)
- [DynamicReports](http://www.dynamicreports.org)

DynamicReports (DR) and DynamicJasper (DJ) are two free and open-source software tools that abstract (and simplify) common tasks with the JasperReports API. If you are considering developing reports programmatically, these tools can cut the development time.

The DR and DJ API packages have the following features in common:

- Dynamic design
- Dynamic column widths
- Stable
- Mix iReport templates with code

### iReport

iReport is a user interface that hides the complexity of calling JasperReports methods directly. In other words, iReport is a fancy and friendlier way to develop reports than coding Java calls manually. The end result is the same: a compiled report (.jasper) file.

### JasperReports API

The JasperReports API provides programmers with a set of Java classes to have a computer create reports based on business needs. The API makes it possible to, for example, develop a web site that allows users to pick the columns they want within a report and then have the report template be created on-the-fly. After the template is ready, a user can then run the report to see the results.

One feature that iReport lacks is the ability to dynamically resize column widths. By using the JasperReports API directly, programmers can create a report template with the optimum column width for the report's result set.

The problem is that the JasperReports API is extremely complex, and parts of it could use more documentation.

### DynamicJasper

The DynamicJasper website notes the following [benefits](http://dynamicjasper.com/features) over the JasperReports API:

- Automatic layout
- Barcodes
- Clean Excel support
- Struts & Grails support

The API examples show a good working of object-oriented principles. The web site offers many examples, and the Javadocs are sparsely commented. The [forum](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dynamicjasper/support?source=navbar) is more active than DynamicReports.

**Update:** The project is now on [GitHub](https://github.com/FDVSolutions/DynamicJasper). No more forum, but you can request a [Professional Support](http://dynamicjasper.com/support/professional-support-eng/)

### DynamicReports

The DynamicReports website notes the following [benefits](http://www.dynamicreports.org/features) over the JasperReports API:

- Inherited designs

The web site offers many examples, but unfortunately the Javadocs do not have a lot of comments. Further, the [forum](http://www.dynamicreports.org/forum) appears less active than either JasperReports or DynamicJasper.

### Summary

If you are happy with DynamicReports I'd say stick with it, otherwise try DynamicJasper.

Comment: Thanks @Dave, very nicely organized!

Comment: @kospiotr you should accept the answer (click the check mark) if you think it is good

Comment: The links for the forums seems that are swapped, the link in DynamicJasper point to DynamicReports and vice-versa. The description is also weird. Anyway, link for DynamicReport forum: http://www.dynamicreports.org/forum/ and DynamicJasper (which is broken ATM of this post): http://dynamicjasper.com/forum/

Comment: DynamicReports Website is no more reachable, any ideas?
http://www.dynamicreports.org

Comment: DynamicReports can now be found and is continued on [github](https://github.com/dynamicreports/dynamicreports)

Comment: Docs are at: https://dynamicreports.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ (Read the Docs).

Answer (score 9):

I've just spent a few days using and evaluating the different reporting options above and thought I would add my 2 cents into the mix.
I've built the same report (Profit & Loss) in JRXML, Dynamic Jasper and Dynamic Reports.
I needed a solution which would output well in both PDF and excel formats and had the ability to handle dynamic columns.

Here's what I found:

**JRXML**

Found it very tedious to use with and without using iReport. I've had experience using JRXML before and I still found it a real battle to get the report to display correctly in both PDF and Excel. I had to use a lot of workarounds by hiding and displaying some fields based on if it was going to be PDF or excel. Dynamic columns are not handled well.

**Dynamic Jasper**

At first I was finding Dynamic Jasper pretty good to work with but had some problems with having absolute control over the layout and putting additional controls on the report. It seems that if your report is column based than it works fine. I couldn't work out how to add a subreport to the detail section and had to add it to the group header or footer.

**Dynamic Reports**

In my opinion Dynamic Reports is the most flexible and easiest way to create dynamic jasper reports. The syntax is easy and intuitive and I found it very quick to get up and running. You do column based report like Dynamic Jasper but also have the options to drop components strait onto the title, detail or other areas of the report. It uses a flow layout so you just drop components into the report and the display in that order. Export to both PDF and Excel was consistent.

The last and most significant benefit of Dynamic Reports is the support and update activity. DynamicJasper has not had forum activity or support in well over half a year while DynamicReports is not only actively updated but also the developer (Ricardo Mariaca) actively monitors the forum and responds quickly to questions.

Answer (score 4):

About a year ago, I came across DJ. My experience with DJ was the best as there were several minor glitches that needed workarounds. However, I found those problems when the project was almost completed and as those workarounds already existed, I continued to use DJ.

After few months, I found DR and learnt that DR has a better structure than DJ. My next project will definitely use DR.

To be frank, I use DJ 3.1.x series and did not try any newer version. I also did not use DR extensively yet.

Answer (score 1):

I am a big fan of DynamicJasper but recently I switched to DynamicReports 4.0.1 (at the time, DynamicJasper latest release is 5.0.3).
With much better API in terms of readability and usability, DynamicReports provides much more flexibility to design reports on the fly. There are also plenty of samples on its website that fosters new ideas and some tutorials that help you start fast. This [link](http://www.mkyong.com/java/reporting-in-java-using-dynamicreports-and-jasperreports/) is a good starting point too.

The only issue I had starting to use DynamicReports was that with JasperReports and DynamicJasper, I was used to create the JasperReport first (design) and then pass the JasperReport object along with a datasource to JasperFillManager.fillReport(...) method to create the JasperPrint object.
With JasperPrint, the only thing is to set the data source before creating the JasperPrint by report().toJasperPrint() method.
You can lookup for usages of a component builder or any utility in its source code to see how to make use of a special feature.